# How i can change icon in local_notification flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification, flutter-notification

Please help me how i can change notification icon.I'm using local_notification package for show notification.
see the below images

[image]

[image]
[image]

I have changed ic_launcher images for changing notification icon. what other things should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Just change from

```
@mipmap/ic_launcher
```

to

```
ic_launcher
```

If that doesn't work, try disabling the minify features in `build.gradle`

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        shrinkResources false
    }
}
```